# Why isn't Javascript not working in Visual Code Studio

Tags: javascript, linux, visual-studio-code, chromebook

I keep getting the error  `/bin/sh: 1: /home//User/App_Java.js: not found [Done] exited with code=127 in 0.024 seconds`. I tried editing the settings.json and adding `"javascript": "home/username/App_Java.js`, but that just gave me the error `/bin/sh: 1: /home/username/App_Java.js: Permission denied`. It was working just fine two days ago. What do I do?

Here is what my setting.json looks like now

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern",
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/bin/python3",
"javascript.validate.enable": false,
"javascriptBooster.formattingOptions": {
    
},
"code-runner.executorMap": {

    "javascript": "/home/schirayil30/hello/node-v18.17.0.tar",
    "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
    "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "zig": "zig run",
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "php": "php",
    "python": "python -u",
    "perl": "perl",
    "perl6": "perl6",
    "ruby": "ruby",
    "go": "go run",
    "lua": "lua",
    "groovy": "groovy",
    "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
    "bat": "cmd /c",
    "shellscript": "bash",
    "fsharp": "fsi",
    "csharp": "scriptcs",
    "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
    "typescript": "ts-node",
    "coffeescript": "coffee",
    "scala": "scala",
    "swift": "swift",
    "julia": "julia",
    "crystal": "crystal",
    "ocaml": "ocaml",
    "r": "Rscript",
    "applescript": "osascript",
    "clojure": "lein exec",
    "haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have `node` installed?

Comment: *It was working just fine two days ago* - what did you change?

Comment: Node is installed. I even tried reinstalling it and it didn't work. I didn't change anything it just stopped working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add to your question the full settings.json and the full error that you are getting. Please have a look at [How Do I Ask A Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: That tutorial worked fixed it.